# Android browser background-size: cover; issue

Tags: android, html, css, background-image

I know there are already posted questions about this issue, but I'm renewing topic only because none of the answers are working for me.
So the problem is that `background-size: cover` doesn't seem to be working in android native browser and the chrome android browser, the image in the beginning displays good like fullscreen, across the whole screen, but when you scroll, the background remains up and is not moving along the screen.

code I used for `background-size: cover`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body.gallery{
    background: url(../img/bg-gallery.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Visual of the issue
[image: the visualization showing background-size:cover; issue on android browsers]